# Remove the .html extension from every file in a simple HTTP server

Tags: http, go, server

I want to make it so when someone visits a page on my Go HTTP server, they won't see the `.html` extension.
E.g. when they visit `https://example.org/test` they will see the content of `https://example.org/test.html`.

My code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("public/"))

    http.Handle("/", http.StripPrefix("/", fs))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

Comment: You'll need to add on `.html`, test if the file exists, and if so, serve that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is to implement [http.FileSystem](https://godoc.org/net/http#FileSystem) using [http.Dir](https://godoc.org/net/http#Dir).  The advantage of this approach is that it takes advantage of the carefully written code in http.FileServer.

It will look something like this:

```
type HTMLDir struct {
    d http.Dir
}

func main() {
  fs := http.FileServer(HTMLDir{http.Dir("public/")})
  http.Handle("/", http.StripPrefix("/", fs))
  http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

The implementation of the [Open](https://godoc.org/net/http#FileSystem.Open) method depends on the application requirements.

If you always want to tack on the .html extension, then use this code:

```
func (d HTMLDir) Open(name string) (http.File, error) {
    return d.d.Open(name + ".html")
}
```

If you want to fallback to the .html extension, then use this code:

```
func (d HTMLDir) Open(name string) (http.File, error) {
    // Try name as supplied
    f, err := d.d.Open(name)
    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        // Not found, try with .html
        if f, err := d.d.Open(name + ".html"); err == nil {
            return f, nil
        }
    }
    return f, err
}
```

Flip the previous one around to start with the .html extension and fallback to the name as supplied:

```
func (d HTMLDir) Open(name string) (http.File, error) {
    // Try name with added extension
    f, err := d.d.Open(name + ".html")
    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        // Not found, try again with name as supplied.
        if f, err := d.d.Open(name); err == nil {
            return f, nil
        }
    }
    return f, err
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am quite new in go, so this helped me a lot

Comment: Another option is to check if the file has an extension first using `if filepath.Ext(name) == ""`. If it doesn't, then try `name + ".html"` first, falling back `name`.

Answer (score 4):

So basically you want the `http.FileServer` functionality, but you don't want clients having to enter the trailing `.html` extension.

Another simple solution is to add it yourself, at the server side. This is how it can be done:

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.URL.Path += ".html"
    fs.ServeHTTP(w, r)
})

panic(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
```

And that's all.

If you want this file server to also serve other files (such as images and CSS files), only append the `.html` extension if it has no extension:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if ext := path.Ext(r.URL.Path); ext == "" {
        r.URL.Path += ".html"
    }
    fs.ServeHTTP(w, r)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but it cannot be done by serving the files using `http.FileServer()`.

Instead, create a custom handler for the `/` route. Inside the handler, serve the requested file directly using `http.ServeFile()`.

```golang
viewPath := "public/"
http.Handle("/", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // hack, if requested url is / then point towards /index
    if r.URL.Path == "/" {
        r.URL.Path = "/index"
    }

    requestedPath := strings.TrimLeft(filepath.Clean(r.URL.Path), "/")
    filename := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s.html", viewPath, requestedPath)
    http.ServeFile(w, r, filename)
}))
http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
```

The `.html` suffix is added to every request path, so it'll point correctly towards the html files.

```golang
path / -> ./public/index.html
path /index -> ./public/index.html
path /some/folder/about -> ./public/some/folder/about.html
...
```