# How do I eliminate file extensions in my code but still be able to develop HTML?

Tags: html, github-pages, file-extension

I have been using Github pages to make my personal website. I am having a problem because when I eliminate file extensions in my code, I can't work on my code locally using Chrome.

I have come across this website (https://rsp.github.io/gh-pages-no-extension/) that explains how to use Github pages without having extensions show up in your final "pushed" product. It just says exactly what you'd expect; remove ".html" from your links in your code.
However, this elimination of file extensions doesn't allow me to load my website using Chrome.

For example, if I have an index.html file that links to test.html, I would use the following line. This allows me to open index.html in Chrome, and have a link to test.html to make sure my code is correct.

'''Click here!'''

However, when following the website I linked above, I should use the following code to eliminate extensions in my final product.
'''Click here!'''

This works as intended, but now I have to go through each of my files, and change the extensions. Additionally, it no longer works locally because Chrome doesn't understand what to do with '''test''' instead of '''test.html'''.
I don't want to keep pushing to Github (this usually takes a minute or two), so how can I quickly load my website locally without having to constantly add/remove the extensions?

Comment: Which static site generator are you using? Jekyll?

Comment: I'm just pushing my files to a github repo with github pages turned on. I remember reading somewhere that GH Pages automatically runs on Jekyll, but I haven't done any extra setup besides pushing my html/css files.

Comment: Try running a local HTTP server as such: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server#Running_a_simple_local_HTTP_server

Comment: Alternatively, run `jekyll serve` and try testing in the `localhost:<port>` URL it runs your site on.

Comment: I followed this tutorial based on what you were talking about (https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll) and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a local file server which will open your html or non html files, as in "[Remove the `.html` extension from every file in a simple HTTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57281956/6309)" (in [Go](https://golang.org/))

```
func (d HTMLDir) Open(name string) (http.File, error) {
    // Try name as supplied
    f, err := d.d.Open(name)
    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        // Not found, try with .html
        if f, err := d.d.Open(name + ".html"); err == nil {
            return f, nil
        }
    }
    return f, err
}
```

That way, you can support both locally.