# Go http.FileServer http.DIr remove the .html suffix mux router

Tags: go, router, mux

I'm serving a static folder using mux.

[image]

Navigating the "/" on my server renders index.html, and navigating to "/help.html" renders the help page. Is there a way I can dynamically serve this folder and remove the html suffix on routes?

This what I am currently doing.

```
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static")))
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57281010/remove-the-html-extension-from-every-file-in-a-simple-http-server) might help you.